# nav css not working after jquery .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

My navigation has a border-bottom on hover, after you slide down on the site my first nav gits hidden and my 2nd nav gets shown. The navs have the same css, but my border-bottom on the 2nd nav doesn't work. Is this a problem with my css or jquery? Can anyone help me fix this?

HTML:

```
<header>
        <a href="#home" id="logo" class="smoothScroll">
            <img src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
            <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
            <a href="#projects" class="smoothScroll">Projects</a>
            <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="header" class="fade">
        <a href="#home" id="logo" class="smoothScroll">
            <img src="img/logo-white.png">
        </a>
        <nav>
            <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
            <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
            <a href="#projects" class="smoothScroll">Projects</a>
            <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
        $('header').show();
        $('header').removeClass('slideUp');
        $('header').addClass('slideDown');
        $('#header').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('header').addClass('slideUp');
        $('#header').removeClass('hide');
    };      
});
```

CSS:

```
header, #header{
  height: 75px;
  background: rgba(26, 28, 30, 0.75);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
}
header{
  display: none;
}
#header{
  background-color: transparent;
}
nav{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 22.5px; 
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 55;
}
nav a:link, nav a:visited{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fffffa;
}
nav a:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, 
  background-color .5s ease;
}
nav a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fffffa !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your JQuery is having some syntax issues in the id selectors. Make sure to include `#`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
        $('#header').show();
        $('#header').removeClass('slideUp');
        $('#header').addClass('slideDown');
        $('#header').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#header').addClass('slideUp');
        $('#header').removeClass('hide');
    };      
});
```

Edit

Per feedback, I have re-visited this issue and have crafted a fiddle with my interpretation of what I believe will solve this. Continuous feedback will be great in getting this resolved.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100 ){
        $('header').addClass('hide');
        $('#header').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#header').addClass('hide');
        $('header').removeClass('hide');
    };      
});
```

### [Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jr7kc6es/)

Comment: No that is not the problem, my first nav is in the <header> and my second is in a <div> with id "header"

Comment: Don't understand the upvotes here - `<header>` obviously is a HTML5 element that does not need an identifier. Furthermore, four of the same selectors in a row could easily be chained for cleaner code.

Comment: @Shikkediel thank you for your feedback. Re-visiting this question, I can see your concern. There is some confusing because of a few things, a lack of fiddle and loose interpretation of intent, especially regarding the `<header>` element and the `<div id="header">` element. I have re-crafted, after reading the question multiple times, a focused attempt to solve what I understand the issue to be.

Comment: Cudos for revisiting. After looking into the code, I have to admit it's a bit confusing. The classes that are applied don't have any corresponding CSS and the only method that seems to effectively be doing anything is the first `$('header').show()`...

Answer (score 0):

The first problem in your script is HTML code.
You should put the second nav inside the header element like this:

```
 <header>
     <nav id="first-nav">
        <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="smoothScroll">Projects</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
     </nav>
     <nav id="second-nav">
        <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a>
        <a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="smoothScroll">Projects</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a>
     </nav>
 </header>
```

I gave the id of "first-nav" and "second-nav" for easy handling.
Second problem is your jQuery. In your **if** condition, you tell jQuery to hide the **header** element when the browser has been scrolled more than 100. That's the problem because **nav** element need to be used inside **header** element.

I have edited your jQuery.

```
   $(document).ready(funciton() {
      //hide the second nav
      $('#second-nav').hide();

      //when the scroll event fired
      $(window).scroll(function() {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
               $('#second-nav').show();
               $('#first-hav').hide();
           }
           else {
               $('#first-nav').show();
               $('#second-hav').hide();
           }
      }); 
   });
```

If there is anything that is not clear please let me know, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: This is a better way to write my html, but it doesn't fix why my underline works on the first nav and not on the second nav